# Which 3 daemons to upload on humanoid targets in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

There are perks in the Breach Protocol branch which give you buffs if 3 or more daemons are uploaded in the same network:

[image]

[image]

It is not clear how to use those perks effectively on humanoids as there are only two human-daemons which you can learn from perks: basic **ICEpick daemon** and the **Mass Vulnerability daemon**. The other daemons you learn from perks can be used on turrets and video cameras only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two legendary quickhacks which have a passive effect that grants you additional daemons to upload on humanoid targets:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Despite the fact that this is not readily apparent, many* enemies are, in fact, on the same network as the various Cameras and Turrets they're milling about.

You can confirm they are via the "Ping" quickhack -- if you "Ping" a Camera (or Microwave, or whatever else is handy)

In such a case, you can upload the "Disable Cameras" or "Disable Turrets" Daemon to a humanoid target and still trigger "upload 3 daemons" effects (it's how I got the Christmas Tree Attack achievement!).

The trouble with this, however, is that sometimes the cameras or turrets are on an isolated network (again, confirm via "Ping"). In this case, your only options are to make use of the extra Daemons granted from Legendary quickhacks (as per [Viktor's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/380331/336)), as Daemons with no effect (such as "Shut Down Cameras" on humanoids) do not show up on the Breach screen at all.

Comment: You are right, there are often cameras and turrets in the same network and in those cases one may get the 3 perk daemons uploaded. But to be honest, the turret and camera daemons are so weak that I don't want to invest perk points in them.